# Windows batch file to copy multiple SSIS packages to SQL Server using DTUTIL command

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, ssis

I am trying to copy multiple ssis packages to SQL server using a windows batch file.
I have the below dtutil command which works fine.

```
for %I in (*.dtsx) do dtutil /FILE "%I" /COPY SQL;"//%~nI" /DestServer SQLServer
```

what should i change in this command to make this to a bat file. Also i need a log file of the deployment.

Comment: You get that text, copy and paste into a text document then change the extension to .CMD. Now you have a batch file.

Comment: you want to make it a .bat file. Open your notepad and paste your code in it. Then Save As your file with filename.bat. Paste this .bat file in location from where you want it to execute. Then open Command Prompt goto the location where the file is copied and call the filename.bat to execute

Comment: it throws an error (*.dtsx) was unexpected at this time.